# reading from IDbCommand using an inherited custom IDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, downcast, idatareader

I have made a custom class inherits `IDataReader` and have successfully
implemented a custom ServerWriter `sqlBulkCopy` with the custom class which uses a C# object instead of `DataTable`.

That proved to be a more efficient approach as I suspected.

Now I am trying to `Read` and I have some problems

This is the `IDataReader`:

```
// get Server Data Table Object IDataReader
public class GetSDTOIDataReaderM : IDataReader
{
   //private IEnumerator<MyTestObject> enumerator = null;

   public MySqlDbTableObject.Raw.SqlDbTableM propSqlTbl { get; set; }

   // implementing relevant GetValue(), filedCount() and Read()
   // this is how I did with WriteToServer
   public bool Read()
   {
       return ++this.ReaderRowsCount < this.propSqlTbl.Table.ElementAt(0).Row.Count;
   }
}
```

The object is mapped exactly as its corresponded SqlTable.

Setting an `SqlCommand` to ExecuteReader() on my custom IDataReader did not work so I have tried with
`IDbCommand` which then it did compile, but still when trying to read 
I get an error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' to
>   type 'GetSDTOIDataReaderM'

```
this.propComunicator.AsGetSDTOCom().SqlCmd.Connection.Open();
//this is the line of the error
using (this.propComunicator.AsGetSDTOCom().SDTOIDataReader = (Raw.Comunicator.Raw.GetSDTOIDataReaderM)this.propComunicator.AsGetSDTOCom().SqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
{

}
```

As write to server it did work, **how can I implement it correctly with `Read`?**

**UPDATE**

A little more about my modules

```
public class TransManSF
{
    public enum CommunicatorTypeS { Reader, Adapter, GetSDTOReaderA, SqlBcpyIDataReaderM };
    public enum DbIntreactorTypeS { TableObject, TableRowObject, Sproc, SqlCmd };
    public enum SqlCmdActionS { NotSet, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DROP };
    public enum SqlCmdStrSelModeS { Single, RecentEfected, count, All, Top10, Top100, Top1000 };
    public enum SqlCmdStrSelOrderByS { NotSet = 0, Asc = 1, Desc = 2 };
    public enum SqlCmdStrSetterModeS { Single, Multi};
    public enum STDOTypeS { NotSet, ServerWriter, ServerTableGetter, ServerBiDerctional }
    public enum SprocTypeS { Sproc, TvPSrpoc }
    public enum TransExecActionTypeS { WriteToServer, GetTable }
}

public static TransMan.Raw.ComunicatorCLF.BulkCopyComSCL AsBulkCopyCom(this TransMan.Raw.ComunicatorCLF.ComunicatorM SelfCom)
{
    return (TransMan.Raw.ComunicatorCLF.BulkCopyComSCL)SelfCom;
}

virtual public void ExecuteTransaction(AppMods.DataBase.TransManSF.TransExecActionTypeS parSelectedTransType, TransManSF.SqlCmdStrSelOrderByS parExecOrderByS, int OrderByOrdinal = 0)
{
    if (parSelectedTransType == AppMods.DataBase.TransManSF.TransExecActionTypeS.WriteToServer)
        using (this.propComunicator.AsBulkCopyCom().Conn)
        {
            this.propComunicator.AsBulkCopyCom().Conn.Open();
            using (var IDRdrServerWriter = this.propComunicator.AsBulkCopyCom().ServerWriter)
            {
                var Eng = this.propExecuter.AsBulkCopyExec().Engine;
                Eng.BulkCopyTimeout = 240;
                Eng.WriteToServer(IDRdrServerWriter);

            }
            this.propComunicator.AsBulkCopyCom().Conn.Close();
        }
    else if (parSelectedTransType == AppMods.DataBase.TransManSF.TransExecActionTypeS.GetTable)
    {
        var DreaderCom = this.propComunicator.AsDReaderCom();
        using (DreaderCom.SqlCmd.Connection)
        {
            DreaderCom.SqlCmd.Connection.Open();
            using (DreaderCom.Driver = DreaderCom.SqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (DreaderCom.Driver.HasRows) while (DreaderCom.Driver.Read())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < DreaderCom.Driver.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            var CurRdrColumn = DreaderCom.Driver.GetValue(i);
                            this.Table[i, 0] = CurRdrColumn;
                        }
                    }
            }
            DreaderCom.SqlCmd.Connection.Close();
        }                           
    }
}


public struct customComConfgBulkCopyA
{
      public TransManSF.CommunicatorTypeS ComType;
      public customComConfgBulkCopyA(TransManSF.CommunicatorTypeS ctrComType = TransManSF.CommunicatorTypeS.SqlBcpyIDataReaderM)
      {
          this.ComType = ctrComType;
      }
}
public sealed class BulkCopyComSCL :CustomComA
{
     public new Configurations.comunicator.customComConfgBulkCopyA Meta;
     public SqlConnection Conn { get; set; }
     public Raw.SqlBcpyIDataReaderM ServerWriter { get; set; }
}

public class SqlDbTableM : SqlDB1stTransA
{
     virtual public DbSchema.Raw.TableDictionaryA TableDict { get; set; }
     public virtual new TransMan.Raw.Configurations.SDB1stTransConfgF.SDTOMetaA Meta { get; set; }
     virtual public Raw.ColumnSetsCollM Table { get; set; }
     public override TransMan.Raw.ComunicatorCLF.ComunicatorM propComunicator
     {
         get
         {
              return base.propComunicator;
         }
         set
         {
              base.propComunicator = value;
         }
     }
     public override TransMan.Raw.Executers.ExecuterM propExecuter
     {
         get
         {
             return base.propExecuter;
         }
         set
         {
             base.propExecuter = value;
         }
     }
     public SqlDbTableM(TransManSF.STDOTypeS ctrTransType)
            : base(TransManSF.DbIntreactorTypeS.TableObject) { }
}

public sealed class GetSDTOComSCL : CustomComA
{
    public new Configurations.comunicator.customComConfgGetSDTOReaderA Meta;
    public new IDbCommand SqlCmd;
    public Raw.GetSDTOIDataReaderM SDTOIDataReader { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does propComunicator.AsGetSDTOCom() return? Is this a class you can get your hands on?

Comment: @RePierre yes  sure I will add an update 5 minutes

Comment: @RePierre If there's more info needed I will be happy to explain and share sorry it took 25 minutes

Comment: In your update AsGetSDTOCom() is still missing. Looks like it's returning SqlCommand rather than IDbCommand. Can you show that part of the code?

Comment: @HarshShah now it does, it uses a SqlDataReader that's as an alternative look at the bottom class this should be the one to be used and this is what it converts to when .AsGetSDTOComSCL() (SCL added to mark it is last descendent of type/model)

Comment: It looks like your approach is a bit off. You shouldn't really be implementing IDataReader unless you are writing your own database drivers which is something you really don't want to do. Can you please be more specific as to what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Randy the closest thing to my intent is `IDbProviderFactory ` suggested by @jods..

Comment: @Randy the result  maybe (if successfully implemented / coded)a **oneliner** database transaction method... covering almost any scenario.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking to build a DAL (Data Access Layer) -- Are you looking to be able to do something like this: DbProvider.GetProvider("ConnectionName").ExecuteQuery("sp_MyStoredProcedure", args)?

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer: you can't change the type returned by `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`.**

It will always be an instance of `SqlDataReader`.

Various solutions:

## 1 Wrap things where it makes sense to you.

If you go to the extreme, write your own `IDbProviderFactory` that wraps a `SqlConnection` with its own connection, command and datareader class.

For instance, that's what Miniprofiler does to instrument all SQL requests and collect execution times, number of rows, etc. [Source code](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/tree/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Data)

Or you may wrap just the reader with some kind of extension method, like so: `sqlCmd.ExecuteReader().AsMyReader()`. What `AsMyReader()` would do is return a custom `IDataReader` that does your stuff and delegates to the actual `SqlDataReader`.

## 2 Use existing helper libraries

I am not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve when reading stuff, but there exists good libraries in this space. No need to come up with your own solutions.

[FastMember](https://code.google.com/p/fast-member/) ([Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastMember/)) allows creating `IDataReader` interfaces around any `IEnumerable<T>` or `DataTable`. It is made to be easily usable as a seed to `SqlBulkCopy` to easily insert data with max. performance into a SQL Server table.

Also, to ease executing SQL queries and parsing their results, [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) is awesome.

Comment: looking at first link the custom `DbCommand` is the start of a core of a solution ? if I will use this as the command will it make life easier on the custom `IDataReader`?  `public class ProfiledDbCommand : DbCommand, ICloneable`

Comment: No, the start of everything is `DbProviderFactory`. It creates its own `DbConnection`, which create their own `DbCommand`, which create their own `DbDataReader`.

Comment: ok so I will continue to investigate from the source `DbProviderFactory` thanks a lot for now  !

Comment: still stuck with standard `SqlDataReader`, didn't have the time to implement / test  the closest suggestion to my intent  e.g `IDbProviderFactory `